# jquery datepicker is not working when it is in partial view in Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have textbox in partial view

```
 <input type="text" id="txtStartDate" />
```

and I have referenced script files are

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("focus", "#txtStartDate", function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    });
```

I have tried in as normal view page  it is working, but when set is partial view it is not working, is this problem with referenced jquery datepicker scripts ? if that a problem is there any solution for that, please help me anyone.

Comment: it should be type="text" right?

Comment: sorry it is typing problem here, but in my view textbox is model type.

Comment: It's not working how? Does your `onfocus` callback get called?

Comment: Yes, it is triggering, but showing like datepicker is not undefined

Answer (score 0):

While rendering the control in partial view you can write

```
       <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#txtStartDate").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
<input type="text" id="txtStartDate" />
```